# map() function on pandas DataFrame in python does not work as expected

Tags: python, pandas

I tried the following code and worked on it for a long time to correct it. But I do not know what I am doing wrong.

```
    def hiLow(x):
    if x > 10:
        print(x, 'is greater than 10')
        df['High/Low'] = 'High'
    else:
        print(x, 'is less than 10' )
        df['High/Low'] = 'Low'

df['total'].map(hiLow)
```

I expected it will add 'High' in the second and third rows of the 'High/Low' column.

When I replaced `df['High/Low'] = 'High'` and `df['High/Low'] = 'Low'` with `df['High/Low'] = x` it prints 15 for all rows.

In the image,

1. This output is correct
2. Why is this all returned 'None'
3. Why is this showing 'object' when at point 4 it is showing as 'int64'

[image]

Comment: The problem is that `df['High/Low'] = 'Low'` replaces the entire column `High/Low` with 'Low' (the same for `df['High/Low'] = 'High')` and then the functions returns `None` (therefore it produces a Series of Nones as you see). You want to return a single value (return 'Low'), not  mutating directly the column of `df` inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def hiLow(x):
    if x > 10:
        print(x, 'is greater than 10')
        str_answer = 'High'
    else:
        print(x, 'is less than 10' )
        str_answer = 'Low'

    return str_answer

df['High/Low'] =  df['total'].apply(lambda x: hiLow(x) )
```

Comment: using lambda in `.apply(lambda x: hiLow(x) )` is redundant, you can and should simply do `.apply(hiLow)`